Oscillation in op amp output
I am working on an amplification circuit to an electret condenser microphone with gain of 5 using an Op-Amp in inverting configuration as shown in the picture.
The reason behind choosing 5 is because the average maximum output
Of the condenser microphone is 200mV and the maximum voltage possible of the speaker is 1.4V (calculated through the power formula)
I chose the value of the resistor R2 to be 10Kohm to be able to use ceramic capacitor C2 of 440nF to get a high pass filter of cutoff frequency about 30Hz.
The value of R3 is 50Kohm so that the gain is around 5 and C3 is 330pF to have a low pass filter of cutoff frequency about 10KHz.
After wiring the circuit, I got an oscillation that I can't measure accurately as I don't have access to an ociliscope. But I noticed that the frequency of the oscillation gets higher as the value of C2 gets lower and vice versa. Also removing the condenser microphone doesn't seem to remove the oscillation. I thought that it would be some noice out of a DC current so I tried using a capacitor in series with the speaker but the problem haven't been solved.
I don't know much about oscillation in Op-Amp as I just studied it. I hope I cleared the problem enough, and thanks in advanced.

A condenser microphone requires a DC current for it to work. This won't happen with C4 in series with the microphone but, it's not all that clear how the microphone is connected and, regarding the 741 op-amp please read this: Reasons not to use a 741 op-amp

@Andyaka The capacitor supposed to resemble the condenser microphone, It is my fault it is not clear in the schematic, thanks by the way.

In real life (outside a sim program), a 741 cannot drive an 8 ohm load.  This is a big problem, and might be contributing to the oscillation.
Another, and greater, contributor is the lack of power supply decoupling capacitors.  Most ICs, and analog ICs in particular, are designed with the assumption that the power rails will have a very low source impedance at the frequencies of interest.  This means that wiring inductance and resistance must be neutralized.
The most common way to do this is to add one or two capacitors from each power pin to GND.  The typical value is a 0.1 uF ceramic, as close as possible to the power pins with the shortest possible leads.  In many of their application notes, Analog Devices recommends an additional 10 uF to 100 uF electrolytic capacitor in parallel with the 0.1 uF cap.
